# Why is the typescript compiler not happy with as casting?

Tags: typescript

```
[1]   Line 2:24:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon.
[1] 
[1]   1 | export function castString(name: string | string[] | null): string {
[1] > 2 |     return name as string;
[1]     |                        ^
[1]   3 |   }
```

The linter is happy but compiler is not happy

Comment: What about forcing an expression separate form the return, as in `return (name as string);`?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? This code compiles perfectly fine in playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzQQwGcYBlGKTFAcwAoV8BbYALjmIurgB83zKqA2gF1ucFEgA2EgJSt2-OAG8AUHDhRgMJFFz0mcIrw5UA3MoC+QA